# Multiple DropDownLists Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a method to make a select menu that has some items, and when you click on one of these items , another list opens?

Comment: You can't "open" a select using javascript at all.  The only option you have is to use a replacement that does have an open method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use multi-level menu?

You could use external libraries, for example: http://www.egrappler.com/multi-level-hierarchical-jquery-menu-jqsimplemenu/